# How to convert hex in format 00-00 to double?

Tags: c#, hex, double

I am getting values in a format like this 00-C6 (Hex). It complains when I try to convert it to double (format execption). What to do?

```
    public void check()
    {
        double low;
        double high;
        percentageCalculator(4095, 5, out low, out high);
        Dictionary[] A_1 = {Max_1, Min_1};

        for (int i = 0; i < A_1.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToDouble(A_1[i].CurrentValue) <= low) || ((Convert.ToDouble(A_1[i].CurrentValue) >= high))
            {
                Fault++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `A_1[i].CurrentValue` data type? a `string`? Also, `Hex` could be `Integer` or `Floating-Point` representation. In your case, is the `Hex` representing `Integer` or `Floating-Point`?

Comment: @Ian I know that the data type is a string. I'm not sure about the representation though...

Comment: To me it *looks* like small int representation. Because for `double` or `float`, you would normally have `4-byte hex`

Comment: @Ian I've checked, it is uint16

Comment: Try `int.Parse(A_1[i].CurrentValue.Replace("-", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)`. It will interprete the hex string as integer

Comment: @Mocke OK, great. Then it is an integer representation, as expected. ;) also please check if the value is `Big Endian` or `Little Endian` representation.

Comment: @Domysee thanks alot, it works!

Comment: @Ian thanks alot for your help! :)

Comment: This all gets to be a lot easier when you do this in the original language this code was written in and you use a telephone to talk to the developer.  Keep it legal, this is a site where programmers make a living and it is not from this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `Hex` `00-C6` `string` represents `Integer` value (because if it represents `floating-point` value like `float` or `double`, it must consists of `4-byte` or `8-byte`), then one way to process it is to split the `Hex string`:

```
string hexString = "00-C6";
string[] hexes = hexString.Split('-');
```

Then you process each element in the `hexes` like this:

```
int hex0 = Convert.ToInt32(hexes[0], 16);
int hex1 = Convert.ToInt32(hexes[1], 16);
```

If the hex is little endian, then your `double` value would be:

```
double d = hex0 << 8 + hex1;
```

And if it is big endtion, your `double` will be:

```
double d = hex1 << 8 + hex0;
```

The key here is to know that you can convert hex string representation to `Int` by using `Convert.ToInt32` with second argument as `16`.

You can combine all the steps above into one liner if you feel like. Here I purposely break them down for the sake of presentation clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
        string hexnumber = "00-c6";
        double doubleValue = (double)Convert.ToInt32(hexnumber.Replace("-", ""), 16);
```